# How to generate javadoc for non-public classes in a .java file

Tags: java, javadoc

I can't figure out how to generate javadoc for non-public classes in a .java file.

Suppose I had a java file HelloWorld.java that looks like this

```
/**
   The hello world class.
 */
public class HelloWorld 
{
   ...
}

/**
   The hello class.
 */
class Hello
{
   ...
}

/**
   The helping class.
 */
class Helper
{ 
   ...
}
```

If I typed in `javadoc -d *.java`, it only generates javadoc for HelloWorld class, how can I generate javadoc for Hello and Helper classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the *manpage* of `javadoc` (`man javadoc`):

> `-public`: Shows only public classes and members.
>   `-protected`: Shows only protected and public classes and members. This is the default.
>   `-package`: Shows only package, protected, and public classes and members.
>   `-private`: Shows all classes and members.

So call it with `javadoc -package -d *.java` or `javadoc -private -d *.java`.

Comment: Thanks again. And here's how to express adding the `-private` in your build.gradle file if you're using that tool: ```javadoc {
    options.addBooleanOption('private', true)
}```

Answer (score 0):

On eclipse, menu Project -> Generate Javadoc, by default, the visibility in on Public, you can change it to Package or whatever will be suitable for you.